# Referencing an object in an included php page - and how to hide it

Tags: php, javascript, dom, instance

So since joining I've learned a lot - compared to where I was - but I still don't know the terminology and functions well enough I suppose... so here's my problem:

I'm making several js-based galleries. The idea being that there will be 3-4 pages containing some thumbnails that will populate a specific div with the corresponding art and copy (a div I'm calling using innerHTML) and so far that works. Here is the script:

```
function changeDiv(target,id) {
var target = document.getElementById('generic');
var id = document.getElementById(id);
target.innerHTML = id.innerHTML; 
}
```

This works great... when I have the 'target' and all 'id's in the same page. I even went as far as using a php include on the page (I added it to the footer) and nested it inside an inline div that I set to visibility:hidden. A shot in the dark but this worked too. EXCEPT that my footer was now about another 100px taller with nothing but blank space. Apparently it HID the content, but made plenty of room for it.

But what I really want to do is include the source of the divs I'm calling (we'll call them artwork.php) into the gallery page ( ...and gallery1.php) the same way a css or js is linked in the header or the same way it is included with a php tag but without messing up any of my objects.

I hope that made sense, but in brief: How can I call an external php document that won't display but can be called upon by the js?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry but I guess it didn't make sense to me. But based on what I understood you want a frame like functionality wherein you can include another php file inside a div. If thats not what you need can you simplify your question?

Answer (score 0):

1) `visibility:hidden`; keeps the place on the page. Use `display:none` instead.

2) Jo have two possibilities.

a) Use Ajax (google it!) if your artwork.php will change dynamically.

b) Use artwork.php as JS file, ie like this:

```
<?php
/* artwork.php */
header('Content-type: application/javascript');

echo "var myImages = [{'name':'First image','src':'image1.jpg'},{'name':'Next   image','src':'image2.png'}];\n";
?>
//... any other JS functions here ...
```

And gallery1.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="artwork.php"> </script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm i am not actually getting what u are trying to say but i think this might help

> save your php page lets say "artwork.php"
>
> then use the jquery Load to call the page and hide the div where you have loaded the page.

```
$("#any_div_u_want").load('artwork.php',function(){
      $(this).hide();
});
```

now u can show the div which contains your php script wheneveer u ant with just

```
$("#any_div_u_want").show();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually pretty novice to most of this so I'm trying to start with js before I jump to jquery but I'll keep this in mind for the next round.